# What is the kubectl command for removing a subject from a rolebinding or cluserrolebinding

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, rbac

I want to use kubectl to add/delete subjects from a k8s rolebinding or cluserrolebinding

Following kubectl command adds a subject to a rolebinding or cluserrolebinding

```
kubectl set subject clusterrolebinding <name> --user=<user>
```

But I couldn't figure out how I can delete a subject using kubectl

Answer (score 0):

`kubectl set subject` doesn't support removing subjects from created ClusterRoleBindings or RoleBindings.

If you create a `RoleBinding` or `ClusterRoleBinding` from a file you can [remove extra subjects](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#kubectl-auth-reconcile) by using

```
kubectl auth reconcile -f <config.yaml> --remove-extra-subjects
```

> The [kubectl auth reconcile](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#kubectl-auth-reconcile) command-line utility creates or updates a manifest file containing RBAC objects, and handles deleting and recreating binding objects if required to change the role they refer to.
>
> This is preferred to 'apply' for RBAC resources so that
>   semantically-aware merging of rules and subjects is done.